# Is it valid syntax to assign variables with a colon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties, linkedin-api, assignment-operator

I saw this on the LinkedIn developer docs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key:    [API_KEY]
  onLoad:     [ONLOAD]
  authorize:  [AUTHORIZE]
</script>
```

Is this valid JavaScript syntax? I understand that colon is normally used to set the properties of an object, so I'm a bit confused with this example using it without the context of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the script tag won't actually be treated as JavaScript because the `<script>` tag has a `src` attribute. The script that you're loading iterates through all of the `<script>` tags, sees if any of them are loading `platform.linkedin.com/in.js`, and then parses the body of the tags with JavaScript.

This is actually invalid HTML and really unintuitive, so don't do it. If a script tag has a `src` attribute, it must either be completely empty or contain just JavaScript comments ([**source**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts)), so it isn't a good idea to rely on lenient browser behavior.

Comment: So platform.linkedin.com/in.js is the one parsing the content of the script tag? Hmm..you're saying I shouldn't use it, do you know if there's another way to set those variables required by in.js? Because from what I understand, the script uses that syntax. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: @beefjerky: Yep. That's the format that the LinkedIn script assumes, so unless you want to rewrite their script from scratch, you'll have to use their format. I was just saying that you shouldn't use this sort of format in your own scripts.